# Qt Camera Example - changing settings does not work

Tags: c++, qt, camera

I have built and run the Camera Example project from the examples in Qt (QtCreator -> examples).
All went correctly.
I can run the program and display video stream from my laptops camera (Lenovo X220) and from my android phone (using DroidCam Client in the background).

The example has many options, that you can change.
I can use the sliders to adjust Exposure Compensation or Quality. But they do not appear to work.
Nothing except form image capture does not appear to work. The same goes for the QML example.

Has anyone tried those examples?
Is there a way to make the functions provided by the example work?
Is there another way to make those changes?

I am using Window 10 with the latest updates, but I have tried the example a couple moths ago, and the results were the same.

Comment: Not all cameras will support all settings.  You can probably check what *is* available using [`QCamera::supportedViewfinderSettings`](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qcamera.html#supportedViewfinderSettings) as well as the other `QCamera::supported...` APIs.

Comment: @Szpaqn, My suggestion in addition to referring to the examples .. you show the relevant code  .. as there are a number of examples ..